# PageList with variable content from filters don't refresh

Tags: android, pagedlist

I had to filter PageList content by transfering filter parameters `MinAge` and `MaxAge` to `ItemDataSource` class:

```
public class ItemDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Item> {
    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Item> callback) {

        loadData(Util.getMinAge, Util.getMaxAge);
    }
    // and so on in loadBefore and loadAfter methods
}
```

Here's refresh method:

```
public void refresh() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        ItemViewModel itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this)
                .get(ItemViewModel.class);
        final ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this);

        itemViewModel.itemPagedList.observe(MainActivity.this,
                new Observer<PagedList<Item>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Item> items) {

                        adapter.submitList(items);

                    }
                });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

But this method don't re-create `ItemDataSource` that contains new filter parameters, so I get refreshed list but with old parameters.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: if you want to refresh `DataSource` you have to call `invalidate()` method - see [Updating Paged Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource#updating-paged-data)

Comment: @pskink can you show example of using ```invalidate()``` in code?

Comment: see https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/paging-beyond-room or http://androidkt.com/paging-library-datasource/